# Plotting a function using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, procrustes

I have the following function

```
def procrustes(data1, data2, data3):
              ...
```

which returns

```
return mtx1, mtx2, mtx3_prime, disparity
```

mxt1, mtx2 and mtx3_prime, are all arrays. disparity is a float

I want to plot  mtx1, mtx2, mtx3_prime on a graph. how best can i do this? I tried

```
plt.plot(procrustes(data1, data2, data3))
plt.show()
```

but that returned a value error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: you could plot all three them on the same graph as `plt.plot(mtx1) plt.plot(mtx2) plt.plot(mtx3_prime)`

Comment: gives me an error if i try to do that `NameError: name 'mtx1' is not defined`

Comment: what variable you used to store the return from function

Comment: i didn't store it in any variable

Comment: store it first like this `mtx1, mtx2, mtx3_prime = procrustes(data1, data2, data3)` and then do that

Comment: still getting the name error

Comment: have return the values correctly? does the function is implemented by you? have you checked if it returns the correct values?

Comment: Yes it returns the correct values. Am even calling the function to make sure it does and its working. If i run `mtx1, mtx2, mtx3_prime = procrustes(data1, data2, data3)` it returns the following  error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`